# How can I restrict Flask-User sign ups to users with emails on a specific domain?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm building a Python web application using Flask along with Flask-User. I want to be able to restrict user registration to users that have an email on a specific domain (i.e. whoever@**example.com**)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could validate the E-Mail in the RegisterForm, so only users with E-Mail ending on example.com will be allowed to register. If you are using [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) you can check the documentation of [WTForms for custom validators](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validators.html#custom-validators).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at the documentation!

Answer (score 2):

You could do it validate it before sending the form, like this:

```
DOMAINS_NOT_ALLOWED = ['yahoo.com', 'baidu.ch', 'example.com']
email_domain = request.form['email'].split('@')[-1]

if email_domain in DOMAINS_NOT_ALLOWED:
    return "You're not allowed to register from this email provider."
```